# Partition A Gridded Rectangle into a Specified Number of Similarly-Sized Smaller Rectangles

Tags: split, geometry, grid, partitioning, rectangles

I need to completely partition a gridded rectangle of integer width `w` and height `h` into `s` smaller rectangles (of any shape or size) in a way that minimizes the area of the largest of these smaller rectangles.  (Let's focus on the non-trivial cases where `s < (w * h)`)

Note!  This is a **gridded** rectangle.  It is *not* infinitely divisible.

#### Example...

Split a 2x3 into 2 smaller rectangles.

**Bad:**

[Here, one rectangular partition has an area of 1x2=2; the other, an area of 2x2=4.  They could be made more even.  (I.e. minimizing the size of the largest one.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj1Wk.png)

**Good:**
[Here, the two rectangular partitions are of size 3x1=3.  Thus, the largest partition has an area of 3 which is smaller than in the previous example.  (And, can be confirmed visually to be minimized.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCbHM.png)

#### I Tried...

I found [this JPL paper](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20110016825/downloads/20110016825.pdf) that describes a method that achieves similar objectives.
However... in some cases, it ends up prioritizing partitions that are as square as possible instead of optimizing the evenness of their sizes.
The above **2x3 example** demonstrates this.  Using this method yields the "Bad" partitioning.

(Also, there's a small typo in the JPL paper.  `r_b0` should be `(y_b+1)*(r-r_t) - (h-h_t)`.  (The `+1` is incorrect.)

I'm looking for a method that will always prioritize evenness of area.  I don't care how square the resulting partitions are.

Any help is greatly appreciated.